# GWT Cell List Ubinder

Tags: list, gwt, cell, uibinder

Because of requirements of my development I need create a GWT cell list with UiBinders inside them. Can anybody give me an example of how to do it?

I am looking in showcase of gwt but I do not find any case equal.

Tnaks a lot!

Comment: Please have a look at [Working with GWT Cell Widgets](http://www.apptio.com/blog/working-gwt-cell-widgets).

Comment: Thanks for asking Braj. I have read this but I have some doubts.

1) It use UiRenderer instead of UiBinder. I need a UiBinder with a picture, some string and three buttons with onClick event handler. Could I achieve it whit UiRenderer. I have read a lot on internet but I can not obtains a clearly idea.

2) In the example of use, in class CellListExample it shows the code to create a CellList but I have a doubt. How can I use this example? I mean how is the way to create a list with UiBinder to show it in a celllist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look into the official documentation: [GWT Project Ui Cell widgets](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html)

When you use `UiRenderer` you are using `UiBinder`, you need to think as `UiBinder` as something which generates DOM from `ui.xml` templates, and if you use `UiRenderer` you are describing that DOM structure as a html directly instead of using "GWT normal stuff (like `<g:Label />`)".

So there are related concepts.

About your questions:

1) Yes, you can do it, but using html and your css. The way of attaching handlers are pretty easy, I'll show you an example:

```
public class YourTypeCell extends AbstractCell<T> {
   static interface Renderer extends UiRenderer {
     void render(SafeHtmlBuilder sb, String id, String name, String img);
     void onBrowserEvent(CommentCell o, NativeEvent e, Element p, T value);
  }

  private final Renderer renderer;

  public YourTypeCell(...) {
    super(BrowserEvents.CLICK, BrowserEvents.MOUSEOVER);
    ....
    renderer = GWT.create(Renderer.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, final T item, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    String id = ...;
    String img = ...;
    String name = ...;
    renderer.render(sb, id, name, img);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent,
      T value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<T> valueUpdater) {
    renderer.onBrowserEvent(this, event, parent, value);
  }

  @UiHandler({"field1"})
  void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event, Element parent, T value) {
    ...
  }

  @UiHandler({"field2"})
  void onReplyComment(ClickEvent event, Element parent, T value) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also the ui.xml file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM 'http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent'>
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' >
  <ui:style>
    .clear{
      clear:both;
    }
    .cssOne {
      ....
    }
    .cssTwo {
      ....
    }
  </ui:style>

  <ui:with field="id" type="java.lang.String"/>
  <ui:with field="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
  <ui:with field="img" type="java.lang.String"/>

  <div ui:field='field1' class="{style.cssOne}">
    <div ui:field='field2' class="{style.cssTwo}"> 
      <ui:text from='{name}'/> 
    </div>
    <p><ui:safehtml from='{img}'/></p>
  </div>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

About the CellList examples you can find it in the previous url and in the javadoc http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html

You can link both classes (`CellList` and your custom cell) with `CellList`'s constructor:

```
CellList<T> cellList = new CellList<T>(new YourTypeCell(...));
```

Comment: Thanks Apanizo for your answer it has been too useful for me and I have achieved make what I wanted. Work with UiBinders give a powerfull way to create pretty user interfaces.

Comment: Hi! I want to do something else with uibinder. I post it here because it is related to the previous ask and it could be usefull for another people. I wanted to handle on click event (it was solved) but now i need, when the user click in field2, change the text of "<ui:text from='{name}'/>". I guess I have to do something like do renderer the UiBinder again.

Do you know how can I do it? Thanks in advice.

Comment: I'd do with GQuery. I need to text, but based on my memory, creating the var in Cell @UiField DivElement field2; , and then, inside the field2's ClickHandler if you GQuery.$(field2).html("pepito");, it should work. Let me know if not.

Comment: This is exactly the method that I was applying but I was wondering if there was another own method of UiBinder to do it. With GQuery it works fine. Thanks.